# Sync folders between Windows 8 and Windows RT (Surface RT, MicroSD card)

Tags: microsoft-surface, windows-rt, micro-sd-card

I'm loving the Surface RT as a decent go-between device, great for meetings and conferences etc, especially with OneNote.

I have a 64 GB microSD card for the Surface RT and would like to sync specific folders from my Windows 8 PC to the Surface RT (ideally to the MicroSD card).

How can I do that?

Comment: Isn't that what SkyDrive is supposed to address? - Sorry I don't have a Win8 device.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft deliberately limited the folder sync functionality of skydrive on the Surface RT. The speculation is that the smaller storage space would quickly fill up for those people who have 100GB cloud drives.  They are protecting themselves from negative feedback from people who don't get why they just filled up their surface after just getting it.

This page discussed a way to map the skydrive access to a specific drive on the RT: http://rashedtalukder.com/how-to-map-skydrive-folder-on-windows-rt-desktop-mode/

However, this isn't the synced solution that allows offline access to the files